# Time complexity - two unsorted arrays

Tags: time-complexity, brute-force, space-complexity

I just had a quick question on time complexity for the following

> Given two unsorted arrays a1 and a2, merge them together, remove
> duplicates and put into ascending order

I can solve this in O(nlogn) time in Java, but I'm interested to see how this would be solved with a brute force implementation, along with the time and space complexities.

Comment: That's pretty impressive that you can solve this in logarithmic time. Best I can do is O(n log(n)), maybe O(n) if I can do a radix sort. I'm not sure what you mean by "brute force" exactly. Could you elaborate? Do you mean trying every permutation of the elements of the two arrays until you find the one that's sorted?

Comment: Sorry, I meant O(nlogn) time, I'll get that edited. But as a thought experiment, I'm just looking to see how other, worse performing approaches would be implemented.

Comment: No problem. I don't see how brute force really applies here-- this is not a search problem and it's hard to do any worse than your approach. You'd have to go pretty far out of your way, i.e. using a bad sorting algorithm like bubble sort. If you want to get really bad, do the permutations described above, which is horrible exponential TC and won't scale beyond a few elements, or just try random configurations of the array until you get the desired result, both approaches basically bogosort. In any case, the sorting dominates the TC so just make the sort dumber.

Comment: I guess that's more along the lines of what I'm looking for, as I'm fairly new to time complexity. Given the criteria above, how would a Bubble sort affect the time and space complexities?

Comment: You can look all these sorts up on wikipedia and compare the complexities